# worst case running time of the following code

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

I am attending a course online and stuck at the following question. What is the order of growth of the worst case running time of the following code fragment as a function of N?

```
int sum = 0; 
for (int i = 1; i <= N*N; i++)   
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        sum++;
```

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: How many times will `sum++` be executed?  Have you figured that part out?

Comment: total it will execute sum++ `N*N!` (factorial of `N*N`).

Answer (score 1):

The execution of this depends on the size of N.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= N*N; i++)
```

Value of i varies from `1` to `N*N`. The inner loop variable `j` depends on `i`.
So for every i, inner loop is executed i times. `sum++` will be executed N<sup>2</sup>((N<sup>2</sup>)+1)/2 times. **O(N<sup>4</sup>)** will be the time complexity of this loop.

Comment: What does O(4) means?!

Answer (score 0):

the code will run everytime (N*N+1)C2 times

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Sorry to hear that, did not want to criticize the author..will be more carefull nextime